# Adding Node.js server to laradock

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, laradock

I have a simple node.js microservice doing some important asynchronous tasks. I am trying to dockerize one of my laravel apps using laradock now I also want to add that microservice in laradock. I am very new to docker and cant figure out what I have to do.

I have tried adding a separate node.js container. But it's not working.

in my docker-compose.yml I added another service: like

```
### NODEJS ##############################################
nodejs:
  build:
    context: ./nodejs
    args:
      - LARADOCK_NODE_VERSION=${NODE_VERSION}
  volumes:
    - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
  expose:
    - "3000-3010"
  extra_hosts:
    - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
  environment:
    - TZ=${NODE_TZ}
  depends_on:
    - workspace
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
```

inside my nodejs folder there is a dockerfile:

```
ARG LARADOCK_NODE_VERSION=latest
FROM node:${LARADOCK_NODE_VERSION}-alpine

LABEL maintainer="Huadong Zuo <admin@zuohuadong.cn>"

RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata ca-certificates && npm install pm2@latest -g 

WORKDIR /var/www/hotelszone_node_partner

EXPOSE 3000-3010

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "node","hello.js"]
```

my nginx config

```
#server {
 #    listen 80;
 #    server_name node.com.co;
 #    return 301 https://node.com.co$request_uri;
 #}

server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  #listen 443;
  #listen [::]:443;

  server_name node_partner_app.test;

  #ssl on;
  #ssl_certificate /var/certs/node.com.co/cert.pem;
  #ssl_certificate_key /var/certs/node.com.co/privkey.pem;
  #ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  #ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


location / {
    proxy_pass http://node_partner_app.test:3003;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
    log_not_found off;
}

    error_log /var/log/nginx/node.com.co.local_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/node.com.co.local_access.log;
}
```

I am trying to make my main laravel app send a request to the node app like simple get requests.

Comment: Adding a new nodejs container would be the way to go so do share how you tried doing that and how it's not working

Comment: thanks for replying I have edited my question please take a look.

Comment: Assuming nginx is also a container and is on the same network then it should be able to forward requests to the nodejs container using `http://nodejs:3003` as the hostname

Comment: What is the issue? You have to use `nodejs` as a host on the laravel app config for it to be able to talk to the NodeJS app, and the `nodejs` app needs to use the laravel (nginx) host name to send request to the laravel app

Comment: @apokryfos I have updated my nginx  config  like `proxy_pass http://nodejs:3003;` when I visit the site on `node_partner_app.test` it returns 502 bad gateway... and in error logs i see `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

Comment: @can you please elaborate...

Comment: It tries to connect to the nodejs container on port 3003 and is not able to. Make sure your container is started successfully and whatever is listening on port 3003 started and is actually listening